# Integer division using gpuR

Tags: r, parallel-processing, gpu

I'm trying to compute a large distance matrix using a custom function. To speed this computation up, I am trying to put all computations on the GPU. One part of the computation I'm performing runs into an error that can be reproduced as follows:

```
require('gpuR')
a=gpuVector(c(5,4,3,6,7),type='integer')
d=a/2
Error in gpuVecScalarDiv(e1, e2, 0) : integer not currently implemented
```

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: You are welcome to make requests on the github [here](https://github.com/cdeterman/gpuR/issues).  If you do, I can certainly make this possible.  Note, integer division in R is also done via the `%/%` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that should indicate a  possible solution.
The product of two vectors of integers is not currently implemented:

```
library(gpuR)
A <- seq.int(from=0, to=999)
B <- seq.int(from=1000, to=1)
gpuA <- gpuVector(A)
gpuB <- gpuVector(B)   
gpuC <- gpuA %*% gpuB
```

> Error in gpuVecInnerProd(x, y) : integer not currently implemented

But we can convert `A` and `B` from integer to numeric and the inner product works nicely under `gpuR`:

```
A <- as.numeric(seq.int(from=0, to=999))
B <- as.numeric(seq.int(from=1000, to=1))
gpuA <- gpuVector(A)
gpuB <- gpuVector(B)    
gpuC <- gpuA %*% gpuB

all(A%*%B == gpuC)
[1] TRUE
```

In your example:

```
a <- gpuVector(c(5,4,3,6,7)*1.0)
d <- a/2
d[,]
[1] 2.5 2.0 1.5 3.0 3.5
```

An interesting note. If we convert `A` and `B` matrices of integers in `gpuMatrix` objects, we do not get error messages from `gpuA %*% gpuB` but the results is wrong:

```
A <- matrix(seq.int(from=0, to=999),nrow=1)
B <- matrix(seq.int(from=1000, to=1),ncol=1) 
gpuA <- gpuMatrix(A)
gpuB <- gpuMatrix(B)
print(gpuA)

Source: gpuR Matrix [1 x 1,000]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    2    3    4

print(gpuB)

Source: gpuR Matrix [1,000 x 1]
     [,1]
[1,] 1000
[2,]  999
[3,]  998
[4,]  997
[5,]  996

gpuC <- gpuA %*% gpuB
print(gpuA %*% gpuB)

Source: gpuR Matrix [1 x 1]   
     [,1]
[1,]    0

print(A%*%B)

          [,1]
[1,] 166666500
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Good explanation of the current version.  I just recently noticed your answer here and the noted multiplication bug.  The issue is documented [here](https://github.com/cdeterman/gpuR/issues/86) and it is now fixed in the 'develop' version on github.